# how to use locale fontion reading files

Tags: c, function

Im using c programming and wanna read letters in txt files like "ı, ş, ç, ğ". But locale funstion only working for the code. Cant read inside files properly. How can i fix that?
Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.